# WPF DataBinding with simple arithmetic operation?

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I want to add a constant value onto an incoming bound integer. In fact I have several places where I want to bind to the same source value but add different constants. So the ideal solution would be something like this...

```
<TextBox Canvas.Top="{Binding ElementName=mySource, Path=myInt, Constant=5}"/>
<TextBox Canvas.Top="{Binding ElementName=mySource, Path=myInt, Constant=8}"/>
<TextBox Canvas.Top="{Binding ElementName=mySource, Path=myInt, Constant=24}"/>
```

(NOTE: This is an example to show the idea, my actual binding scenario is not to the canvas property of a TextBox. But this shows the idea more clearly)

At the moment the only solution I can think of is to expose many different source properties each of which adds on a different constant to the same internal value. So I could do something like this...

```
<TextBox Canvas.Top="{Binding ElementName=mySource, Path=myIntPlus5}"/>
<TextBox Canvas.Top="{Binding ElementName=mySource, Path=myIntPlus8}"/>
<TextBox Canvas.Top="{Binding ElementName=mySource, Path=myIntPlus24}"/>
```

But this is pretty grim because in the future I might need to keep adding new properties for new constants. Also if I need to change the value added I need to go an alter the source object which is pretty naff.

There must be a more generic way than this? Any WPF experts got any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you can do this with a value converter.  Here is a [blog entry](http://weblogs.asp.net/marianor/archive/2007/09/18/using-ivalueconverter-to-format-binding-values-in-wpf.aspx) that addresses passing a parameter to the value converter in the xaml. And [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/bencon/archive/2006/05/10/594886.aspx) gives some details of implementing a value converter.

Comment: The fact the value converter can take a parameter seems like a good approach to solving the problem here. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 24):

I use a `MathConverter`that I created to do all simple arithmatic operations with. The code for the converter is [here](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/08/20/the-math-converter/) and it can be used like this:

```
<TextBox Canvas.Top="{Binding SomeValue, 
             Converter={StaticResource MathConverter},
             ConverterParameter=@VALUE+5}" />
```

You can even use it with more advanced arithmatic operations such as

```
Width="{Binding ElementName=RootWindow, Path=ActualWidth,
                Converter={StaticResource MathConverter},
                ConverterParameter=((@VALUE-200)*.3)}"
```

Comment: Nice converter, but this breaks if value is a negative number. A quick hack-workaround would be to use some other sign for minus, not "-" and modify the lists of operands in the code of MathConverter respectively. A real solution of course would require to add more logic while parsing..

Comment: @MaximZabolotskikh A negative number is just `0 - @VALUE`, so users could easily enter it as that. Or as a better solution, just check for a `-` symbol when we expect a numeric token, and if it's found parse it properly. I think I may have actually done that in the copy of the converter I keep in my WPF library...

Comment: 0 - @VALUE will not work. To be more precise, I have a 0-based list and want to show text "element x of y", so I bind index (x) as "@VALUE + 1". However empty list will return -1 as index, so it becomes -1+1, mathconverter splits by operands, than for minus second number is not found, sth like that. So some more parsing should be done. But basically the purpose of my comment was just to point out a possible problem to anyone who might use this code in future. It's a helpful converter anyway.

Comment: Generic Warning: I just spent forever figuring out that those commas are required

Answer (score 6):

Using a value converter is a good solution to the problem as it allows you to modify the source value as it's being bound to the UI.

I've used the following in a couple of places.

```
public class AddValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        object result = value;
        int parameterValue;

        if (value != null && targetType == typeof(Int32) && 
            int.TryParse((string)parameter, 
            NumberStyles.Integer, culture, out parameterValue))
        {
            result = (int)value + (int)parameterValue;
        }

        return result;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Example

```
 <Setter Property="Grid.ColumnSpan"
         Value="{Binding 
                   Path=ColumnDefinitions.Count,
                   RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Grid},
                   Converter={StaticResource addValueConverter},
                   ConverterParameter=1}"
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use multibinding converter such as the following example:

C# code:

```
namespace Example.Converters
{
        public class ArithmeticConverter : IMultiValueConverter
        {            
            public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
            {
                double result = 0;

                for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (!double.TryParse(values[i]?.ToString(), out var parsedNumber)) continue;

                    if (TryGetOperations(parameter, i, out var operation))
                    {
                        result = operation(result, parsedNumber);
                    }
                }

                return result;
            }

            public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
            {
                return new[] { Binding.DoNothing, false };
            }


            private static bool TryGetOperations(object parameter, int operationIndex, out Func<double, double, double> operation)
            {
                operation = null;
                var operations = parameter?.ToString().Split(',');

                if (operations == null || operations.Length == 0) return false;

                if (operations.Length <= operationIndex)
                {
                    operationIndex = operations.Length - 1;
                }

                return Operations.TryGetValue(operations[operationIndex]?.ToString(), out operation);
            }

            public const string Add = "+";
            public const string Subtract = "-";
            public const string Multiply = "*";
            public const string Divide = "/";

            private static IDictionary<string, Func<double, double, double>> Operations = new Dictionary<string, Func<double, double, double>>
            {
                { Add, (x, y) => x + y },
                { Subtract, (x, y) => x - y },
                { Multiply, (x, y) => x * y },
                { Divide, (x, y) => x / y }
            };
        }
}
```

XAML code:

```
<UserControl 
     xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:Example.Converters">
    <UserControl.Resources>
                    <converters:ArithmeticConverter x:Key="ArithmeticConverter" />
    </UserControl.Resources>
```

...

```
<MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ArithmeticConverter}" ConverterParameter="+,-">
            <Binding Path="NumberToAdd" />
            <Binding Path="NumberToSubtract" />
</MultiBinding>
```

Answer (score -1):

I've never used WPF, but I have a possible solution.

Can your binding Path map to a Map?  If so, it should then be able to take an argument (the key).  You'd need to create a class that implements the Map interface, but really just returns the base value that you initialized the "Map" with added to the key.

```
public Integer get( Integer key ) { return baseInt + key; }  // or some such
```

Without some ability to pass the number from the tag, I don't see how you're going to get it to return different deltas from the original value.